# how to connect to mysql database through nodejs application (i use expressjs) with cpanel

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, cpanel

I'm trying to access database from the backend but it doesn't work. My application: https://notaraccoon.site/test_database/.
appjs:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : '103.200.23.139',
  user     : 'admin',
  password : '33s72cpsZYXmAGL',
  database : 'test',
  multipleStatements: true
});

app.get('/test_database', (req, res) => {
    connection.query(`select * from test_table`, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.send(results)
        res.end()
    });  
})
-
app.listen()
```

I am not sure if I file the `host` field true.

Comment: Try using `'http://localhost'` for host

Comment: @RobyRajuOommen but i am deploying it on a hosting service. this Is my application link

Comment: https://notaraccoon.site/test_database/.

Comment: Is your database and application hosted on the same server? Are you using MySQL 8 or 5.7? Is the `bind-address` configured to listen on 0.0.0.0 ?